# How to plot two regressions lines in one plot: two x and 1 y using R

Tags: r

I have a data set called "Data" as following:

| Spending | Score | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2 | 5 |
| 200 | 26 | 89 |
| 1000 | 90 | 65 |

How can I put the regression lines of linear model Number ~ Spending and Number ~ Score in one plot either use `ggplot` or other functions? I would like to visualize the difference of slopes in this plot.

Comment: here's your data `data <- data.frame(Spending=c(100,200,1000),Score=c(2,26,90), Number=c(5,89,65))`. Try to include data as code not photos it makes it easier to help.

Comment: You should start by including some code that you have tried so that we can build off of where you get stuck. As your question is you are asking the good folks of SO to start from scratch, essentially doing all the work for you. There are two methods you can employ here; 1) use the ggplot function `geom_smooth()` or create a data object of predictions yourself and plot those using `geom_line()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a `ggplot2` approach you could use multiple `geom_smooth` to add regression lines for multiple columns of your data:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
  Spending = c(100L, 200L, 1000L),
  Score = c(2L, 26L, 90L),
  Number = c(5L, 89L, 65L)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(y = Number)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Spending, color = "Spending"),
    method = "lm"
  ) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = Score, color = "Score"),
    method = "lm"
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

A second approach would be to reshape your data to long using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` which allows to get the same result with just one `geom_smooth`:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
  Spending = c(100L, 200L, 1000L),
  Score = c(2L, 26L, 90L),
  Number = c(5L, 89L, 65L)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(ggplot2)

dat |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Number) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = Number, color = name)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: The first approach was working fine. But one thing to note is, it is important to bring variables to the scales. I have normalized the variables for this